# Cannot Move File

Tags: linux

I am brand new to all of this server stuff. I setup Linux on my server and the Slim GUI. I am simply trying to move a file from one folder to another but for some reason, no matter how I issue the command, it just constantly says it cannot find either the file or the file path when I can see both very clearly. I have spell checked everything and I tested the file paths existences by using "cd" so I am not sure what else to do here. I attached an image of many of my attempts if that helps.

[image: There is a spelling mistake in the last command but this was fixed and still doesn't work]

Comment: Read any of these please https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/differences-between-absolute-path-and-relative-path-in-linux.html https://linuxhandbook.com/absolute-vs-relative-path/  https://datacarpentry.org/shell-genomics/02-the-filesystem/index.html you're running tons of commands without making sense of what you're doing and what directory you're in right now.

Comment: Also make sure you understand what `~` is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-tilde-expansion/

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov Thank you for the resources. I did some reading online and was following a couple articles about how to do this, but I guess they described incorrect methods since they are not what your guides say. I understand what the commands are doing, but I still in the process of learning correct syntax.

Comment: They probably assumed a different relative path than the one in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please follow Artem's suggestion of doing a bit of research first.

This issue could be resolved with the following commands. Press tab for autocomplete.

```
cd
```

```
cd Documents/java
```

```
mv ~/Downloads/jre-8u301-linux-x64.tar.gz .
```

```
mv ~/Downloads/server.jar .
```

Comment: This worked after specifying the location of the mv right after defining the file. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome. I would advise you to read a book such as The Linux Command Line to get a hang of the basics.